# Can I check a google bigquery query cost programmatically?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I would like to run a bigquery query from python only if it is below a certain cost estimation.
Is there a way to programmatically check the estimated cost of a query before executing it, just like the Web UI (see attached image)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `dryRun` flag. This will return `totalBytesProcessed` i.e. the amount of data that will be processed if the query is executed.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.dryRun

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to run a bigquery query from python only if it is below a certain cost estimation

First, please note - BigQuery UI in fact uses DryRun which only estimates `Total Bytes Processed` leaving another important factor `Billing Tier` unknown.
Use of DryRun of course useful and can help in certain scenarios!

Meantime, I can propose using below two attributes

[`configuration.query.maximumBillingTier`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.maximumBillingTier)
and
[`configuration.query.maximumBytesBilled`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.maximumBytesBilled)

They respectively limit the billing tier and  bytes billed for the job
Queries that have resource usage beyond max tier or have bytes billed beyond max bytes will fail (`without incurring a charge`)